# How to test my Angular login form for full coverage? Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have just changed my login component to be more as Angular would have intended, however I am now getting failures in my test of the kind:

> Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

A problem I have found through debugging with console.log is that no matter what I am passing in to my onSubmit() function, it is seeing a valid form when it should not.

FYI - The login form does behave normally and as expected in practise. It is just the tests that are being funny.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first :

> Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

Means your service does not return an Observable.

resolve it with

```
spyOn(mockAuthService, 'login').and.callFake(() => of(null));
```

Since your callback does nothing
(signature : `this.authService.login(formUser, formPass).subscribe(() => {`), you don't need to return anything, so `null` is fine.

The error following that might be coming from that, since you never go into your subscribe callback, the variables aren't set.

Second thing :

```
function setCredentials(user: boolean, pass: boolean) {
    component.loginForm = formBuilder.group({
      username: user ? 'someUser' : '',
      password: pass ? 'somePassword' : ''
    });
  }
```

Your form has no validator ! It means it's always valid, no matter what you do.

Comment: I am getting the error: `<spyOn> : login has already been spied upon` back, probable since I have `mockAuthService = createSpyObj(['login', 'logout']);` already defined?

Comment: @physicsboy yup, you're going to need to write `mockAuthService.login.and.callFake(() => of(null))` underneath that line to mock the response !